# If $B$ is an essentially finitely generated $A$-algebra, is the module of Kähler differentials $\Omega_{B/A}$ finitely generated?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, modules, finitely-generated

I'm studying the module of Kähler differentials from Eisenbud's *Commutative Algebra*, you can easily get a pdf by typing the name on Google. We have proposition 16.3:

> If $\pi:S\to T$ is a surjective morphism of $R$-algebras, and $I=\ker(\pi)$ we have an exact sequence $$I/I^2\to T\otimes_S\Omega_{S/R}\to \Omega_{T/R}\to 0.$$

Now consider $B$ an essentially finitely generated $A$- algebra, i.e we can write $B\cong S_p$ where $S$ is a quotient of a polynomial ring with coefficients in $A$, $p\subseteq S$ prime. I want to show that $\Omega_{B/A}$ is a finitely generated $B$-module.
Since the right morphism is surjective, showing that $T\otimes_S\Omega_{S/R}$ is finitely generated is enough.

Consider first the case $B=A[x_1,\dots,x_n]$. What seems natural to me is taking $T=B$, and maybe $S=A$ or $S=B$. However I'm not sure if there is necessarily an epimorphism from $A$ to $B$, and $id_B=\pi$ just leads to $\Omega_{B/A}=\Omega_{B/A}$ since $I/I^2=0$.

Do you have ideas?

Comment: Just to make sure, since you don't say in your post, which ring are you hoping to show $\Omega_{B/A}$ is a finitely-generated module over? (Separately, I've made a few formatting upgrades to your post - check them out by using the [edit] dialog.)

Comment: I wanted to point out that if $B$ js an $A$-algebra and $S \subset B$ is multiplicative, there is a canonical identification of $S^{-1}B$-modules $\Omega^1_{S^{-1}B/A}=S^{-1}\Omega^1_{B/A}$.

Comment: Yes sorry I want to show that it's finitely generated as a $B$-module. Mindlack are we don't have a multiplicative set do we ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, $\Omega_{B/A}$ is a finitely-generated $B$-module. Using the notation from your post, we first see that $\Omega_{S/A}$ is a finitely-generated $S$-module from applying the result listed in your post to a surjection $A[x_1,\cdots,x_n]\to S$ as $\Omega_{A[x_1,\cdots,x_n]/A}$ is the free $A[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$-module on the symbols $dx_i$ for $1\leq i\leq n$. Next, we use [the fact](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00RT) that for a ring map $C\to D$ and any multiplicative subset $U\subset D$ we have $U^{-1}\Omega_{D/C}\cong \Omega_{U^{-1}D/C}$ applied to $A\to S$ with $U=S\setminus p$. As the localization of a finitely-generated module is again finitely generated over the localized ring, we have the result. (One proof of this last statement is that finite generation of the $R$-module $M$ is equivalent to a surjective map $R^{\oplus n}\to M$, and as localization is exact we get a surjective map $S^{-1}R^{\oplus n}\to S^{-1}M$ by localizing at the multiplicative set $S\subset R$.)

Comment: Thank you this is much clearer but I still have a few questions. 1) Here can we have $S=A[x_1,\dots,x_m]/J$ and $B=A[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ with $m\neq n$ ? In the definition of essentially fintely generated I don't know if there is a link between the number of variables of $B$ and $S$. 2) Where did we use that $B$ is a polynomial ring here ? Does this still work if $B$ is a quotient of a polynomial ring ? I feel like what we really used here is that $S$ is a quotient, and then we use the fact. 3) Is your fact equivalent to proposition 16.9 (in this proposition we have a tensor product)

Comment: 1) Sure, all we assumed was that we have a surjection $A[x_1,\cdots,x_n]\to S$. We only need one such surjection to deduce that $\Omega_{S/A}$ is finitely generated and it doesn't matter if $m=n$ or not. 2) We did not use that $B$ was a polynomial ring at all - we used that it's a localization of a quotient of a polynomial ring. 3) I do not have this book with me at present and do not know exactly what statement you're talking about.

Comment: That's so great, we only need $B$ to be essentially finitely generated. Proposition 16.9 says : If $S$ is an $R$-algebra, $U\subseteq S$ multiplicatively closed, then $\Omega_{U^{-1}S/R}=U^{-1}S\otimes_S \Omega_{S/R}$

Comment: Yes, that proposition is equivalent to what I used: localizing the $S$-module $M$ at the multiplicative subset $U$ can be written $U^{-1}M$ or $U^{-1}S\otimes_S M$.

Comment: By the way, if this answers your question, it is suggested to click the green checkmark to accept it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).